# Apply function with conditional statement on multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, if-statement, multidimensional-array, apply

I have two 3D-arrays:

```
a=array(1:27, dim=c(3,3,3))
b=array(c(0,2,6,0), dim=c(3,3,3))
```

I'd like to sum up all values in array a along the z-dimension (getting a 2D-matrix) for which the value at the corresponding x,y,z-location in array b is > 0.

I'd prefer a combination of apply (best with a standard function) and an if-statement like

```
summed=apply(a, c(1,2), sum {if(b[b>0])})
```

which gives me syntax error though. What do I miss here?

Comment: maybe `apply(a * (b > 0), c(1, 2), sum)`?

Comment: start with writing a function that works on a simple vector. `sum {if(b[b>0[])}` gives a syntax error because there is syntax error -- actually there are many.  `{` is used to group several statements but here you try to do something else. `if` should be followed by  a single condition `(in parentheses)`  that evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE` and then a statement (possibly a group of statements joined by `{`).

Comment: Suren, so simple but brilliant. Works perfectly, thanks so much :) you gotta make an answer out of this.

Answer (score -1):

We could multiply 'a' by the logical array of 'b'.  By multiplying 'a' by the binary array 'b', those elements that are 0 in 'b' would become 0 in 'a' and 1 * number remains number

```
a* (b > 0)
```

Then, we transpose the array with `aperm` and get the `colSums`

```
colSums(aperm(a * (b > 0), c(3, 1, 2)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   26   16
#[2,]   22   14   34
#[3,]   12   30   18
```

Comment: The b > 0 statement is vital. There could be other values > 0 in b apart from 1, but I just meant to keep the example simple. Sorry, I'll edit that.

Comment: @Elli In that case, you should change the example.  It is creating an impression that the array is binary

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to sum a and b, but sum all a values along the z-dim. b is just the condition, if the corresponding value in a is used for summing or not.

Comment: @Elli Please check if the update is the answer you are looking for

Comment: Yes, this works as intended, very nice! Thank you for your efforts :)
If I had more reputation score here, I would upvote you...